# Looping through Generic Class's collection property

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Although many questions have been posted, none seem to help me on my issue.

I've started a new `Generics` / `Reflection` adventure and I'm just trying to get my head around the syntax and concepts.

I have a `Generic` class with X amount of properties and one being a collection, all is working fine but I'm having problems extracting the values from the collection `props` by property name.

```
foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
    if (property.Name == "Props")
    {
        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(type, null))
        {
            var propertyName = "";
            var newValue = "";
            var oldValue = "";

            sbDescription.AppendLine(strDescriptionVals
               .Replace("{0}", (item.ToString() == "PropertyName") ? item.ToString() : "" + ", "));

            sbAllNotes.AppendLine(strAllNotes
               .Replace("{0}", (item.ToString() == "PropertyName") ? item.ToString() : "")
               .Replace("{1}", (item.ToString() == "NewValue") ? item.ToString() : "")
               .Replace("{2}", (item.ToString() == "OldValue") ? item.ToString() : ""));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've pinpointed the property Props and now I want to loop through that and pull values by property name.

`item.ToString()` just prints the namespace of the class property and not the value

Hoping you kind folk can point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's `type` variable?

Comment: @Sybren it's (T) properties are pretty much the same on each method invocation that's why it's generic.

Comment: It's a very "anonymous" set of features and class's. The problem is retrieving the values from a "collection property" nothing more.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So what type is your collection really? List<T>, IList<T>, ICollection? And what is your variable "type"? This should be the object instance you want the property value from.

Comment: Can you show the class definition for type T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to recursively "dive" into the items properties.

Note, only conceptual code fragments, no guarantee that it works as I write it here:

```
void Print(object value, string propertyName)
{
    if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) || property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
    {
      sbAllNotes.AppnedLine(.. propertyName .. value ..);
    }
    else if ((typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType)
    {
      PrintCollectioType((IEnumerable)value);
    }
    else
    {
      PrintComplexType(value);
    }
}

void PrintCollectioType(IEnumerable collection)
{
  foreach (var item in collection) 
  {
    Print(item, "Collection Item");
  }
}

void PrintComplexType(IEnumerable collection)
{
  foreach(var property in owner.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    var propertyName = property.Name;
    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(owner);
    Print(item, propertyName);
  }
}
```

To print the "Props", do:

```
var props = typeof(T).GetProperty("Props");
var propsValue = props.GetValue(rootObject);
Print(propsValue, "Root");
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing with the code and understanding the logic a little more, it occurred to me that is was as simple as "*Getting the type and Property*" on the `Props` iteration:

```
        //Get the collection property
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.Name == "Props")
            {
                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)property.GetValue(type, null))
                {
                    //Because props is a collection, Getting the type and property on each pass was essential
                    var propertyName = item.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(item, null);
                    var newValue = item.GetType().GetProperty("NewValue").GetValue(item, null);
                    var oldValue = item.GetType().GetProperty("OldValue").GetValue(item, null);

                   sbDescription.AppendLine(strDescriptionVals
                       .Replace("{0}", (propertyName != null) ? propertyName.ToString() : "" + ", "));

                   sbAllNotes.AppendLine(strAllNotes
                       .Replace("{0}", (propertyName != null) ? propertyName.ToString() : "")
                       .Replace("{1}", (newValue != null) ? newValue.ToString() : "")
                       .Replace("{2}", (oldValue != null) ? oldValue.ToString() : ""));
                }
            }
        }
```